# How to send each csv file row over socket using Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

python noob. I want to send each individual row one at a time over to the client from the server using pandas via sockets. My pandas display on the clients cli, but on the server side all the output I get displayed is "None". What is a better way to write the code for my server?

the client...

```
import socket
import pandas as pd
import ipdb

HOST = 'SERVER_IP'
PORT = 42050
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))

dataframe = pd.read_csv(
    "/opt/astral/Walabot-Data/hand-only-target.csv",
    header=0,
    sep=",",
    quotechar="'",
    #skiprows=2
    usecols=['Target #','x','y','x','amplitude','timestamp'],
)


def get_row():
    for row in dataframe.itertuples():
        # ipdb.set_trace()
        print row


while True:
    s.send(str(get_row()))
    break
print "Done Sending"
s.close()
```

the server...

```
import socket
import ipdb

result = ""
HOST = 'LOCAL_IP'
PORT = 42050
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
print "Server running", HOST, PORT
s.listen(5)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print'Connected by', addr

while True:
    data = conn.recv(409600)
    print repr(data)
    if not data:
        break

print "Done Receiving"
conn.close()
```

Comment: `get_row` doesn't return anything explicitly, so it returns `None`. But why involve a data-frame at all here?

Comment: well that was foolish of me. Ok, I changed it to "return row". Now the server only displays one row and quits (over 1000 rows exist) what else did I mess up?

Comment: Because you returned on the first iteration, I can only assume. You need to loop over every row and send it.

Comment: Again, why pandas here?

Comment: "why pandas"  I'm exploring two directions to attempt to solve this. With and without pandas ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53148019/how-to-send-each-csv-row-one-at-a-time-over-socket

Comment: @thefonso I did not downvote them.